# Is there a way to programmatically check pending model changes in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, migration

I am currently in the progress of setting up a team environment for ASP.NET Core WebAPI development, using xUnit for unit tests in combination with GitLab CI. For database communication, we use EF Core.

For EF Core we are going to use Code First Migrations and we are worried that a developer might only update the model and not also create a migration for their model change.
Thus, we want our CI to run all migrations that exist in the codebase, compare them with the current state of the code first model and fail when the code first model state is not equal to the state that results from running all the migrations.

Is there a way to do this? I cannot find anything about this in the EF Core documentation.

Comment: AFAIK there is no possibility to compare the modelstate in the code, but you may use the CLI and generate SQL commands and compare them? Not that kind of clean, but you got a basic comparison.

Comment: I have some code to do that here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/efpt/EFCoreMigrationsBuilder.cs#L101 - but why not consider database first?

Comment: @ErikEJ because EF Core does not support database first and migrations offer loads of benefits. Thanks for the example code, I'lll check it out :).

Comment: @hyvte Thanks for the suggestion, I did certainly think of this but I would prefer a more "clean" approach.

Comment: EF Core supports database first!

Comment: In my experience (similar stack), your integration tests will fail if you use .EnsureDeleted(), .EnsureCreated() on your application factory. This method will create the model according to the current migration state, so the difference between entities and schema will result in an SQL Error being thrown in every test that tries working with that entity at db level. the error is pretty self explainatory. ie: “SQL Ex: theres no column “addedprop” in table blah”. You should be running Tests in CI, so they’ll break and prevent you from mergin the changes without the migration being there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the example code from @ErikEJ, I was able to write the following test that does exactly what I want:

```
    using FluentAssertions;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
    using Xunit;

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains a test that verifies that the
    /// model does not contain any changes that are not included
    /// in the migrations.
    /// </summary>
    public class NoPendingModelChangesTest
    {
        private static readonly string DummyConnectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=DoesNotExist;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests that the current model does not contain any changes
        /// that are not contained in the database migrators.
        /// In other words: tests that the current model state equals the
        /// state that results from all the migrations combined.
        /// </summary>
        [Fact]
        public void ModelDoesNotContainPendingChanges()
        {
            // Do not use the test database, the SQL Server model provider must be
            // used as that is the model provider that is used for scaffolding migrations.
            using var ctx = new MyDatabase(
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDatabase>()
                    .UseSqlServer(DummyConnectionString)
                    .Options);

            var modelDiffer = ctx.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();
            var migrationsAssembly = ctx.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();

            var pendingModelChanges = modelDiffer
                .GetDifferences(
                    migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot?.Model,
                    ctx.Model);

            pendingModelChanges
                .Should()
                .BeEmpty(
                    because:
                        "the current model state should be equal to the state that results from all the migrations combined (try scaffolding a migration)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

For EF Core 6, from @ErikEJ's excellent EF Core Power Tools:

```
var migrationsAssembly = _ctx.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();

var hasDifferences = false;
if (migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot != null) {
    var snapshotModel = migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot?.Model;

    if (snapshotModel is IMutableModel mutableModel) {
        snapshotModel = mutableModel.FinalizeModel();
    }

    snapshotModel = _ctx.GetService<IModelRuntimeInitializer>().Initialize(snapshotModel);
    hasDifferences = _ctx.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>().HasDifferences(
        snapshotModel.GetRelationalModel(),
        _ctx.GetService<IDesignTimeModel>().Model.GetRelationalModel());
}
```

https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/5a16c37c59be854605f3e81d3131011d96c96704/src/GUI/efpt30.core/EFCoreMigrationsBuilder.cs#L98

Comment: It was not initially clear to me that this can simply be tested (with xUnit) with `Assert.False(hasDifferences);`. I hope that saves someone a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using EF (core) 5 you'll need a slightly different version (also adapted from  [@ErikEJ sample code](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/efpt/EFCoreMigrationsBuilder.cs#L101))

```
    [Fact]
    public void ModelDoesNotContainPendingChanges()
    {
        // Do not use the test database, the SQL Server model provider must be
        // used as that is the model provider that is used for scaffolding migrations.
        using var ctx = new DataContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
                .UseNpgsql(DummyConnectionString)
                .Options);

        var modelDiffer = ctx.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();
        var migrationsAssembly = ctx.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();

        var dependencies = ctx.GetService<ProviderConventionSetBuilderDependencies>();
        var relationalDependencies = ctx.GetService<RelationalConventionSetBuilderDependencies>();

        var typeMappingConvention = new TypeMappingConvention(dependencies);
        typeMappingConvention.ProcessModelFinalizing(((IConventionModel)migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot.Model).Builder, null);

        var relationalModelConvention = new RelationalModelConvention(dependencies, relationalDependencies);
        var sourceModel = relationalModelConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot.Model);

        var finalSourceModel = ((IMutableModel)sourceModel).FinalizeModel().GetRelationalModel();
        var finalTargetModel = ctx.Model.GetRelationalModel();

        var hasDifferences = modelDiffer.HasDifferences(finalSourceModel, finalTargetModel);
        if(hasDifferences)
        {
            var changes = modelDiffer.GetDifferences(finalSourceModel, finalTargetModel);
            Assert.True(false, $"{changes.Count} changes between migrations and model. Debug this test for more details");
        }

        Assert.False( hasDifferences );
    }
```

Comment: How would this be migrated to EF Core 6?

Comment: See @Simopaa answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69970295/3786

Answer (score 0):

With the release of EF Core 8, [this is supported natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#checking-for-pending-model-changes).

Expanding on [the answer by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686198/3146354) we can now do the following.

```cs
    public class MigrationTests
    {
        private static readonly string DummyConnectionString = 
            @"Server=localhost;Database=DoesNotExist;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        [Fact]
        public void NoPendingModelChanges()
        {
            // Arrange

            // Do not use the test database, the SQL Server model provider must be
            // used as that is the model provider that is used for scaffolding migrations.
            using var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseModel(ApplicationDbContextModel.Instance)
                    .UseSqlServer(
                        connectionString: DummyConnectionString,
                        sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                        {
                            sqlOptions.UseHierarchyId();
                            sqlOptions.UseNetTopologySuite();
                        })
                    .Options);

            // Act
            var hasPending = dbContext.Database.HasPendingModelChanges();

            // Assert
            Assert.False(hasPending);
        }
    }
```